# Transfer files with special characters from Windows to MacOS

Tags: macos, finder, windows, migration, exfat

I am in the process of migrating from Windows to Mac.
To transfer all my files from an old Windows laptop to a new Macbook I am using an external SSD (formatted as exFAT).

I copied all my files to the external SSD and when I plug that drive in the Macbook many files are missing, not showing up on the drive. If I go back and connect the drive to the Windows laptop, I can verify that the files are *really* on the external drive.

I narrowed it down to files that have special characters in their filename.
For example Ö ([LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d6/index.htm))
Looks like MacOS refuses to recognise the existence of these files. I found that MacOS treats Unicode a bit differently than others by doing Unicode Decomposition, although I am not sure if this is what causing the inability to even see the files on the drive.

How can I work around this problem?
Any help is appreciated.

---

**Update**

Checking the folders on the external SSD via Terminal confirms the non-existence of the files with special characters. I double checked again on Windows, the files exist.

```
% ls -la
total 4096
drwxrwxrwx  1 <user>  staff  1048576 Dec 20 10:12 .
drwxrwxrwx  1 <user>  staff  1048576 Dec 21 11:52 ..
```

This also doesn't return any files:

```
la -laH
```

Checking the disk usage:

```
du -h
```

This returns 1.0M. On Windows I can see 15 files in this folder, around 11.5M in total. The files are also not corrupt and can be opened.

Comment: Open Terminal, then drag the folder that contains the files to the window. That will change to that directory. Post the output with an [Edit] to the question of the command `ls -la`.

Comment: What do you get with the command `pwd`?  Also, be sure to ping me with @Allan in the comments so I am notified

Comment: @Allan, I get the path to the folder that should contain files, but doesn't on MacOS

Comment: @Allan, I am familiar with shell and terminals. So if you wan't me to do more advanced stuff I can do that. As far as I can see MacOS just completely ignores the existence of any file with a special character. 
I also tried a different Macbook and same result.

Comment: If you run `du` on a directory with such files, does the calculated size include those files?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know your tech level, it helps a lot. If the files are there, they should show up.  Maybe they are hidden.  Try `ls -laH`

Comment: @nohillside, "du -h" returns 1.0M. On Windows, I can see 15 files, around 11.5M in total. The files are also not corrupt or anything, I can open them on Windows just fine.

Comment: @Allan, "ls -laH" doesn't show any files. 
I am so confused...

Comment: sorry for asking, but are you 100% sure you look at the same external drive from both the Mac and the Windows system? Do you have an USB pendrive available which you can format to exFAT and the copy a few of those files to it, make sure it gets properly ejected on Windows side and check on the Mac?

Comment: This is confounding.  Can you SSH into your Mac from the Windows machine?  If so, try using SCP to copy the file.  It would be interesting to see how things work with this method.